# Ubuntu 20.04 13900h intel driver kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I want to know about the kernel version that supports intel 13900h intel graphic drivers in ubuntu 20.04.
My laptop renders with cpu not gpu.
Can you give me informations?

Comment: You've not provided your Ubuntu product; only mentioning the release (with Server using the GA kernel by default, and Desktop using HWE by default; though if you *release-upgraded* to 20.04 your default will be determined by your installation media). For newer hardware you need to ensure you're using the HWE kernel stack for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (*which will still only bring you up to early 2022 unless OEM kernel stack exists for your hardware*).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: I am using a Desktop version. I am using 5.15.0 84 But it does not recognize my cpu's graphic driver